# animate cc AS3, Javascript mouseover doesn't change alpha correctly

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, html5-canvas

I have a movie clip inside a movie clip, inside the first movie clip I've created an action, the action says this: when the mouse is over this 'button' then change the alpha of 'these' things to 0.1

the button is located **inside the first movie clip**, where I made the action, the things that I want to change their alpha are located **inside the second movie clip**, which is inside the first, among those things are 2 dynamic texts, they **do** change alpha successfully on hover, the rest of the objects **don't** (they're movie clips) with an instance name.

this is the code:

```
stage.enableMouseOver(10);
this.freegreen.addEventListener("mouseover", freehover.bind(this));

function freehover()
{


        if (clicked!=0)
        {
        this.freenfo.visible=true;
            this.freenfo.varvan.text="sites with free content";
            this.ins.ShutterStock.alpha=0.1;
            this.ins.pond5.alpha=0.1;
            this.ins.b3.alpha=0.1;
            this.ins.p3.alpha=0.1;
            this.ins.b4.alpha=0.1;
            this.ins.p4.alpha=0.1;
    }
    }
```

this is the part the **doesn't** work:

```
        this.ins.b3.alpha=0.1;
        this.ins.p3.alpha=0.1;
        this.ins.b4.alpha=0.1;
        this.ins.p4.alpha=0.1;
```

the rest **does** work, these are 4 symbols with instance names as b3, p3, b4, p4.

the instance name of the second movie clip is called **ins**
the dynamic text is fading correctly, I don't know why the rest doesn't,
I've double checked all names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by restarting animate cc >>